# DataModel for Partial deliveries over quantities of product

Tags: database, data-modeling, datamodel

Consider the following data model. 
With this model, it seems to me we could only make partial deliveries with the entire quantity ordered for a product.

**What should we change in order to allow the partial delivery of the quantities of the product?**

For example, say an order that contains *50 units of product A* and *50 units of product B*.

A first partial delivery could ship to the customer *25 units of product A* and *25 units of product B*.

A second partial delivery could ship to the customer *25 units of product A*, and finally a last delivery *25 units of product B*.

[image]

*Note: [click here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/customers_and_partial_deliveries/index.htm) to get the example data model*

Comment: The Shipments table, like many others, has "other_details."  The diagram isn't meant to show an exhaustive list of all possible columns.  Mohsen's answer gives you the column you need, but there could be many others, like shipper_id, delivery_instructions, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It seams in the model, we have one to many relation between `orders` and `shipments` tables. So it seams partial shipment is conceptually possible. 
 
You will need to add `item-quantity` field to `shipment-items` and `return-items` tables, showing how many items per product is fulfilled.
 
The integrity of data needs to be considered as well.
If a product is unique per order, I mean if you have unique constraint of `{product_id, order_id}` inside `order-items` table, then:

```
SUM (shipment-items.item-quantity) grouped by order_item_id 
-
SUM (return-items.item-quantity) grouped by order_item_id 
<= 
order_items.order-item-quantity
Where order_items.order_item_id = shipment-items.order_item_id
```

Need to be checked inside  your application logic when a shipment is created.

***Hint:*** The above constraint shows all sent items of a product of an order minus all return items of the product of the order, needs to be less than the ordered quantity.